# In ColdFusion, what is the difference between setting a function to a variable and calling a function in hashtags?

Tags: coldfusion, cffunction

I wrote the following function:

```
  <cffunction name="check_session_valid" returntype="boolean">
    <cfif NOT StructKeyExists(session,"username") OR (len(session.username) EQ 0)>
     <script>location.href = 'logout.cfm'</script>
     <cfabort>
    </cfif>
    <cfset session.myApp_start = now()>  
    <cfreturn true>
  </cffunction>
```

In my .cfm page, I can call that function using

```
<cfset session_valid = application.lib.check_session_valid()>
```

**OR**

```
#application.lib.check_session_valid()#
```

What's the difference? Best practice?

Comment: The former is returning a value to another variable, whereas the latter is just outputting the value. Both could be best practice, depending on what you are trying to achieve. I would say that you probably want to return the value into a new variable. So, the first approach is better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you asked about best practice, which is a matter of opinion, I think you can improve your function by having it returning either true or false depending on whether or not `session.username` exists and has a length greater than 0.  Then you can use it like this:

```
<cfif application.lib.check_session_valid()>
code for this condition
<cfelse>
<cflocation href = "logout.cfm">  
<!--- note that cfabort is not necessary --->
<cfif>
```

Regarding your specific question, I think the extra variable, `session_valid`, is a waste of typing.  However, that is simply my opinion.

Not related to your question, I found it curious that you would direct users to a page called logout.cfm.  Often users are directed to a page that allows them to log in.

Answer (score 2):

To be honest, both are valid and both would be considered best practice depending on what you are trying to do.

My rule of thumb is if I will need to use the result of a function call more than once, I will set it to a variable

```
myResult = application.lib.check_session_valid();
```

If I will only need to use the variable once I would do what Dan mentioned

```
if( application.lib.check_session_valid() ){
    // Do stuff
}
```

The difference between the examples you showed are

```
<cfset session_valid = application.lib.check_session_valid()>
```

This will set the variable named `session_valid` to whatever is returned from the call to `check_session_valid()`.

```
#application.lib.check_session_valid()#
```

This will, in .cfm pages, simply render the value returned from the call to `check_session_valid()` assuming it is inside of a `<cfoutput>` tag. There are other places this would also render the value, such as inside a `<cfsavecontent>`.